# Comparing response proportions in a two forced choice task to see if there is a response bias

Tags: chi-squared-test, proportion, z-score

I am doing an experiment where participants have always two options of response (1 and 2) by clicking a mouse button (two forced choice method) during a set of trials. If a participant performed 100% on my experiment, he/she would had to click 50% of the times in 1 and 50% of the times in the 2 bottom.

I want to see if any of my participants have a bias for one of the mouse buttons, thus, I want to compare the proportion of 1'clicks to the proportion of 2'clicks to see if these proportions are sig different. What test should I use? z-score? chi-square?

Thanks a lot :)